# Get all Values of JSON Array

Tags: php, android, json

i am working on an app, where i try to create a friendlist. For this i want to get all friends of a user and show it in my application. But it just show 1 user and not all. Could someone help me?
Here my code:
PHP:

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// Datenbankverbindungsklasse einbinden
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/db_connect.php');

// Klasseninstanz und -verbindung herstellen
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$con = $db->connect();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["bid"])) {
    $bid = intval($_GET['bid']);

$query = sprintf("SELECT Benutzer.benutzername
                           FROM Benutzer
                           INNER JOIN Freundesliste
                           ON benutzer_ID = Freundesliste.Bid_2 and Freundesliste.Bid_1='%d'",
               mysql_real_escape_string($bid, $con));

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $benutzer = array();
            $benutzer["benutzername"] = $result["benutzername"];

            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["benutzer"] = array();

            array_push($response["benutzer"], $benutzer);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no benutzer found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No benutzer found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no benutzer found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No benutzer found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}



$db->close();
?>
```

Android:

```
/** Vorhandene Freunde laden */
    class GetFriends extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FriendlistActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Freunde werden geladen...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Freunde im Hintergrund laden
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bid", bid));

                        // getting user data by making HTTP request
                        // Note that user data url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("LINK", "GET", params);

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received user data
                            JSONArray userObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);  // JSON Array

                            // get all user object from JSON Array
                            for(int i=0;i<userObj.length();i++){
                                json_data = userObj.getJSONObject(i);
                                String friend = json_data.get(TAG_NAME).toString();
                                listadapter.add(friend);
                            }

                            friendlistview.setAdapter(listadapter);


                        }else{
                            // user with bid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all data
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You only fetched one row from the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way, in order to iterate through each row in the result

```
$benutzer = array();    
$response["benutzer"] = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  $benutzer["benutzername"] = $result["benutzername"];

  $response["success"] = 1;

  array_push($response["benutzer"], $benutzer);
}
```

Comment: Nop, just the app will be shut down

Comment: you should turn on error reporting:
 error_reporting(E_ALL); 
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: u got an error.. its not while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
its while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

this works, but now i got 3x null ( but user 1 got 3 friends ). this is right. but the app doenst show usernames :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the result to get all rows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $response["benutzer"][] = $row["benutzername"];
}
$response["success"] = 1;
```

Get off of the MySQL extension and use PDO or MySQLI.